# Retrieve individual counts by grouping SQL query

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I want to retrieve the count for pending inquiries and the count of completed inquiries for each counsellor and display in a table. What is the SQL query to retrieve these data?

```
SELECT CounsellorName, 
  (SELECT COUNT(Status) 
   FROM register WHERE Status='Pending') AS pending, 
  (SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM register WHERE Status='Completed') AS completed
FROM register  
GROUP BY CounsellorName
```

I'm using this  currently, but it doesn't retrieve individual counts for each counsellor.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CounsellorName, 
  sum(Status='Pending') AS pending, 
  sum(Status='Completed') AS completed
FROM register  
GROUP BY CounsellorName
```

it finds counts of pending and completed statuses per counsellorName.